# Trascendence of $e^\pi$ and $\pi^e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, pi, transcendental-numbers

Is there some relation between the trascendence of $e^\pi$ and that of $\pi^e$? I mean: the transcendence of one implies the other or the proofs are independent? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's known if $\pi^e$ is transcendental or not.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Yes, but, if we prove $\pi^e$ is trascendental, this automatically, means $e^\pi$ is trascendental?

Comment: I don't know... However, $e^\pi$ is transcendental; Google "Gelfond's constant".

Comment: [We know $e^\pi$ is transcendental](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Epi+transcendental); [we don't know whether $\pi^e$ is transcendental](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%5Ee+transcendental).

Comment: @Shaun Arf... There are has been a slight mix-up between your two links : both are the same. Maybe you can still edit ?

Comment: Sorry! Hang on a second . . .

Comment: @jibe I've fixed it. Thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: Exponentiation is not an algebraic operation in the way that addition and multiplication are, so it shouldn't be too surprising if transcendence and exponentiation don't have much to do with each other.

Comment: I [edit]ed this question because [titles should not contain `\displaystyle`](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3135/290189).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered in the comments there is no immediate relation between them. $e^\pi$ is transcendental but it is not known if $\pi^e$ is transcendental or not.

If you wish to create a trivial relation you could say that if $e^{\pi}$ is algebraic then $\pi^e$ is algebraic which is something like saying if $0 = 1$ then I am the King of England.